# change default shipping method on button click (ajax call) on checkout page

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, php-5.4, ajax, shipping-methods

How to change default `shipping method` on button click (ajax call) on `checkout` page?

Comment: Do you want to preselect a different shipping method depending on user input, or just change the default selected method globally?

Comment: @alex.ayg, First one. depending on user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from both PHP or JavaScript

If you go the PHP way, you need to edit the `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml` file, and around line 47 you have an if statement

`if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod())`

when this condition returns true, it will set the corresponding method as selected. So you can update the if statement, and check other condition as well

If you want to go the JavaScript way, you need to edit the `skin/frontend/base/default/js/onepagecheckout.js` file