# Pre select custom shipping method in extension code

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

I created an extension to extend Magento with another shipping method. Actually I used [this tutorial](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2011/06/09/creating-a-custom-magento-shipping-method/) to do this. Only difference is that the shipping method only shows up if an item in cart is eligible for this method. So far it works. But now I want to pre select this shipping method. How can I do that? Unfortunately I couldn't find any information about it. The only option I'm seeing right now is to add the logic in the template. But I was wondering if it can't be set in the extenion (app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php) itself.

```
<?php

class Creativ_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Oneitem_Extended_Flatrate1
extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
implements Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface
{
protected $_code = 'extendedflatrate1';
protected $_isFixed = true;

public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

    $items = $request->getAllItems();

    $eligible = false;

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getInsuranceEligible(false)) {
            $eligible = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($eligible) {

        $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

        $method->setCarrier('extendedflatrate1');
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
        $method->setMethod('oneitemflatrate1');
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
        $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

        $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
}

public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array('oneitemflatrate1' => $this->getConfigData('name'));
}
```

}

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If I clearly understand you, we can reduce your question to following:

> How to preselect any shipping method?

If yes - look here: [change default shipping method on button click (ajax call) on checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23509/change-default-shipping-method-on-button-click-ajax-call-on-checkout-page)

Comment: This is almost correct. I was looking for a solution without editing the template so that all my code lives in my extension. It looks like its not possible with PHP (in app/code) but with an extra Js file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome